# SitecoreAIStandardContainerDeployment

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce, personalization, container, kubernetes

I want to install Sitecore with `SitecoreAIStandardContainerDeployment`. I am following up on this link, as recommended by Sitecore. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard/3x/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard_300.aspx

But as per the documentation, We need to extract file as per below recommendation,

1. Extract the `SitecoreAIStandardContainerDeployment.{version}.{revision}.zip`
   archive to any location on your workstation. In the archive, the
   `compose/deploy/<XP_Topology>`
   folder contains a `docker-compose.override.yml` file that you use for
   deploying the images that are created during the build stage.
2. Extract the `SitecoreContainerDeployment.10.*.*.zip` archive, and, in the folder where
   you extracted it, locate the `compose/<yourbaseOS>/<XP_Topology>` folder. In the
   instructions that follow, this folder is referred to as your deploy folder.

But unable to find the link, to download the package, Can you please help me provide the proper link, so that I can download the package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The document you are referring has the link to download these packages. As per the document, download the following packages from the Sitecore Downloads page:

1. [Sitecore Experience Platform 10.1 Container Deployment Package](https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/releases/tag/sxp%2F10.1.0.005207.309)
2. [Sitecore AI Container Package](https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/releases)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I got this experience platform package as per this value "Sitecore Experience Platform 10.1.1 Container Deployment Package"

But,

When I click on this "Sitecore AI container package" link, I got severeral package to download. Kindly help which I need to download here. 
Can you please provide the proper AI package link.

Comment: @biswajitsahu Reading the document I guess you need to download the `Sitecore AI Auto-Personalization Installation package` from this link. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard/3x/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard_300.aspx

Comment: Yes, I agree "Sitecore AI Auto-Personalization Installation package". But once I click this link "https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard/3x/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard_300.aspx" , we need to click "container deployment package"https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/releases, Once I click then, what will be desgire package, can you please suggest.

Comment: @biswajitsahu Once you click on https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard/3x/Sitecore_AI_Automated_Personalization_Standard_300.aspx check the link `Sitecore AI Auto-Personalization Installation package` and you will find the files in this package